# what is static method why use this in Display class in java

Tags: java

i am always use static keyword but don't know clearly what is main purpose of static keyword. can any define  , this is use in java Display method in oop

Comment: class Display{
  
    static void show(Animal c){
      
      c.sound();
      c.hair();
      c.ears();
    }
  
}

Comment: what is work of static in this class

Comment: Read up : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: You need to do some research on your own before asking a question here. There's countless online sources which explain what static is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static methods are those methods can be called without creating its object.
It can be invoked using its class name.

```
Eg. Math.sqrt(25);
```

Where Math is the class name, not an object and static methods can access only static properties of the class.